# Pirates of Barracuda Bay 21322 - Is there a way to get the ship pirating-worthy?

Tags: building, sets, set-modification, ideas

From what I have read, when you convert the island to a seaworthy ship, you are still left with the inn part, and no cannons on the ship. All the portholes are gone or converted to windows.

Is there a way to get the cannons back on the ship? Preferably using only pieces from the set? If pieces needs to be added, what is the simplest way to make that conversion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The review over at Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/49409/review-21322-pirates-of-barracuda-bay) mentions this exact modification:

[image]

> Pearl gold windows are fixed inside each gunport, preventing the deployment of cannons. While this seems slightly odd, **the lattices can be removed** and replaced with cannons, as demonstrated here. I appreciate these options but **some furniture must be removed from inside to create enough space for the weapons**, corresponding with the officers' quarters on historic ships where cannons could replace tables and chairs during battle.

(Emphasis by me)

Comment: Nice find, thank you